# How to get the specific property value from SOPAUI response?

Tags: xml, api, groovy, soapui

[image]Whenever I am executing the testcases, I will get the property value  in response as `myscore` *Arun/ten2016-12-20*

Here the key is `myscore` and value is`Arun/ten2016-12-20`. The date will be changing dynamically as today date append with the text 'Arun/ten'

I tried by adding the below groovy script code but its not working,

```
today = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
log.info today

def s=log.info("Arun/ten" + today);

assert messageExchange.responseHeaders["my_client_update"] == ["s"]
```

I want this script to be passed.

The same i have passed in the script assertion like below,

assert messageExchange.responseHeaders["my_client_update"] == ["s"]

Kindly suggest the solution.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the raw response.

Comment: @Rao thanks for editing, here the response is not the problem, focus is the properties which are getting in the response via soapui

Comment: unless we know how the response content and its response headers, it is difficult to understand the problem itself. Screen shot would help here as well.

Comment: yeah thanks i will update the screenshots @Rao

Comment: Thank you for the edit. So, now what would like to check? Is it that the value in the format `Arun/ten` with today's date or it can be any date with specified format? Please clarify.

Comment: You can check the answer to see if that is helpful.

Comment: yes its very helpful thanks @Rao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Script Assertion` is almost near except that one statement has trivial issue.

Here is what you would need the script to be, and note that below script is using simple regular expression for date as that is dynamic. Of course, you may also use in the same way as convenient to you.

```
/**
* Below is the Script Assertion
* Retrieves the specified header and asserts against the expected value
**/

//Change the header key as needed.
def requiredHeaderKey = 'my_client_update'

//Change the expected value for the above Header key
//Note that below one is using the regular expression to accommodate dynamic date in the header value
def expectedRequiredHeaderValue = "Arun/ten\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"

//You may not be required to change beyond this point of the script.

//Check if the response has headers
assert messageExchange.responseHeaders, "There are no headers in the response"

//Get & Check if the response has required Header and its value is not empty
def requiredHeaderValue = messageExchange.responseHeaders[requiredHeaderKey]
assert requiredHeaderValue, "Value of the response header ${requiredHeaderKey} is empty or null"

if (requiredHeaderValue instanceof List) {
  log.info "Requested header value is ${requiredHeaderValue[0]}"
  assert requiredHeaderValue[0] ==~ expectedRequiredHeaderValue, "Response header value is not matching with the expected value"
}
```

Comment: thanks @Rao suggest some good online tutorial or books to learn the groovy scripting

Comment: Please consider accept & up vote the answer if that is useful. You should be able to find & learn groovy online. The issue is to be able to use it in SoapUI is to know the API. I find this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92WEfVJPJDQ) very helpful to start with.

Comment: yeah thank u so much i will check the video sure @Rao